# PHP - If statement within foreach

Tags: php

So I'm brand new to PHP and am trying to accomplish something pretty simple. Import a text file to an array, have a foreach go through that array looking for a value, and printing the value if found.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$testers = file('test.txt');
foreach ($testers as $test) {echo $test . "<br />";}
```

This works great, each line is printed. Perfect.
I then add an IF statement.

```
$testers = file('test.txt');
foreach ($testers as $test) {if ($test){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```

Also working fine, seems to be returning data. Now if I try and add an operator, it all falls apart.

```
$testers = file('test.txt');
foreach ($testers as $test) {if ($test == "One"){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```

I should say, the text file has in it numbers on each line from "One" to "Six"
I also tried:

```
$testers = file('test.txt');
foreach ($testers as $test) {if ($test === "One"){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```

This also returned nothing...

Any insight would be awesome! Thanks!

What exactly am I missing here? Why is this if statement not returning the value I'm looking for?!

Comment: Try `trim($test) == 'One'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is because [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) by default will include line breaks into each line. Thus, comparison on equality will fail.

You may use:

```
$testers = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

i.e. add flag so PHP won't include line breaks to resulting array items.

If you don't want to list empty lines, there's corresponding `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag, so:

```
$testers = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Comment: Thanks, while the other suggestions are all valid as well, I liked this one as it was simple, to the point and explained what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to make the check instead and do an [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) prior to that to remove empty entries from your `$testers` array.

#### The code...

```
<?php
$testers = array_filter(file('test.txt'));
foreach ($testers as $test) {if (stripos($test,"One")!==false){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare each line if it's equal to another, please check about [strcmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

If you want to see if a line contains a string, please check strpos[enter link description here](https://www.php.net/strpos)

for strcmp :

```
foreach ($testers as $test) {if (strcmp($test,"one")==0){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```

for strpos:

```
foreach ($testers as $test) {if (strpos($test,"one") !==false){echo $test . "<br />";}}
```